# CoffeeScript returns wrong prototype

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In this piece of code below, I am creating a `Test` object and storing it in an array.  I wrote a method to retrieve the test object by name and return it, but it returns the `Array` prototype, instead of the `Test` prototype.  I have attached the example code below, and a codepen.  What am I doing wrong and how do I attempt to fix it.

```
class TestHandler
    constuctor: ->

    testList: []

    addTest: (test) ->
      @testList.push test

    getTestList: ->
      @testList

    getTestForName: (name) ->
      for e in @getTestList() when e.getName() is name
        e

class Test
  constructor: (name) ->
    @name = name

  getName: ->
    @name

testHandler = new TestHandler()
testHandler.addTest new Test 'hi'


console.log testHandler.getTestForName 'hi'
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaxyrX

Comment: It does not return any prototype object? But yes, it returns an array of the objects with that name - as you told it to do.

Comment: No it returns a prototype object of `Array`.  And I am telling it to grab a specific object, but doesn't return the prototype attached to that specific object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the last statement of a function body is a `for` loop, coffeescript takes that entire loop as the return value. In fact, in coffeescript a `for` loop itself is a value, which is the array whose elements are the last line in the `for` body. So you can do something like this

```
x = for i in [0...3]
  console.log('i is', i);
  3 * i
```

which sets `x` to `[0, 3, 6]`. Similarly, if we had

```
f = ->
  for i in [0...3]
    3 * i
```

then `f()` would return `[0, 3, 6]`. A simple fix for you would be

```
getTestForName: (name) ->
  for e in @getTestList() when e.getName() is name
    return e
```

Comment: Omg, this is amazing!  I have been banging my head at this for two days now and never thought it would be returning the for loop as an array!  The implicit return can really mess with my brain logic.  Thank you so much!

Comment: To be clear, "When the last statement of a function body is a for loop" is not entirely correct. Any statement on the last line is getting returned implicitly.

Comment: correct. it goes for list comprehensions as well. or if you do something like a `console.log` statement at the end of a function, it will return void, which is equally confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning the actual object but the list comprehension, you need to explicitly return from the list comprehension

```
getTestForName: (name) ->
    for e in @getTestList() when e.getName() is name
        return e
```

Comment: How would I go about returning the actual object then?  I have very little experience with prototype inheritance and coming from Java this confuses me a ton.

Comment: This has nothing to do with prototypes, it's how coffeescript works. Coffeescript thinks that the last line of your `getTestForName` function is that iteration and since Coffeescript has implicit returns (ie. returns whatever is on the last line of the function body) it's just gonna return that. This particular feature is most prevalent in Ruby for example.